# Using timer to control semaphore in C

Tags: c, multithreading, timer, semaphore

I'm trying to control a process using a timer. (Just trying to see how it works in order to implement it in another program. The purpose of that program is to call a function in a specific interval. But when I did that, it turned out that it was using too much CPU. I'm also trying to avoid using sleep.I got the timer to work, what it was implemented in a while loop, so it was hogging all of the CPU.

What I want is for the timer_handler to unlock the thread so that it can proceed with the rest of the program, and also for it to perform the same exact action at precise intervals.

This is the code that I have so far

```
   int sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value);
   int sem_wait(sem_t *sem);
   int sem_getvalue(sem_t *sem, int *sval);


   int set_count = 0;
   static int count = 0;
   int timer_set();

   sem_t sem;

   struct inits{
    struct sigaction sa;
    struct itimerval timer;

   }inits[1];



   int timer_handler (int signum)
   {

    printf ("timer expired %d times\n", ++count);

    if(sem_post(&sem)== -1){
     write(STDERR_FILENO, "sem_post() failed \n", 18);
     _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     return 0;
    }
    else
     return 0;
   }

   int timer_set(){
    memset (&inits[0].sa, 0, sizeof (inits[0].sa));
    inits[0].sa.sa_handler = timer_handler;
    sigemptyset(&inits[0].sa.sa_mask);
    inits[0].sa.sa_flags = 0;
    printf("sigaction successfull: \n");
   /* Configure the timer to expire after 1000 msec... */
     inits[0].timer.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
     inits[0].timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
     /* ... and every 1000 msec after that. */
     inits[0].timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
     inits[0].timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
     /* Start a virtual timer. It counts down whenever this process is
       executing. */
     if(setitimer (ITIMER_VIRTUAL, &inits[0].timer, NULL) == -1)
      handle_error("timer set failed: ");

     printf("timerset successful\n");

     return 0;
   }
   int main ()
   {

     int s = 1;
     int j;
     int* sval;

     printf("S value = %d\n", s);
   // scanf("\n%d", &set_count);
    if (sem_init(&sem, 1, 1) == -1)
      handle_error("sem_init");
    else{
     printf("sem_init successful\n");
     printf("sem_init has been set  s = %d\n", s);
    }

    printf("j = %d\n",  j=timer_set());
    /* Do busy work. */
    while (1)
      {
       sem_getvalue(&sem, sval);
       if (errno==EINVAL)
        handle_error("Error returned on sem_getvalue: ");

       printf("entered while loop\n, S = %d\n",  *sval);

       while ((s= sem_wait (&sem))==0 && errno == EINTR)
       {
        printf("entered while loop, S = %d\n", *sval);
        printf("entered sem while loop\n");
        continue;
       }
       if (s == -1)
        handle_error("Semaphore Wait failed\n");
        else
         printf("Semaphore Successful\n");
      }
    printf("thank you for using this  timer. ADIOS!\n");
    exit(1);
   }
```

The problem is that it doesn't go through the second loop of while, and freezes.

Sorry I haven't yet figured out how to post proper code, so I apologize if it looks weird. .
Also, I've been researching this for a while now so I apologize if there's something that I have missed in my research which may or may not have answered my question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with `sleep` ?

Comment: It is my understand the `sleep` is not as accurate, and also is less efficient.